# Warning: ... you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more

Tags: support

I was going to ask a question and I got the following warning:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and
>   you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a
>   good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

As you can see in my [account page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19017/becko), I only have five questions on this site, I don't think they have had such a bad reception. Is this a bug? Or is there a reason I am receiving this message?

Comment: For non-mods: I see seven questions, two deleted with scores of zero. [The details provided by the network](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) suggest that these count toward a ban, although we don't actually know the rules (or indeed control what that page says). I'm not really sure what we 'locally' can say about this!

Comment: Further to that, I guess out of a total of seven questions you currently have only three with a positive score: that might be it.

Comment: @JosephWright -- one of the zero-score questions has one up- and one down-vote.  (there is no comment explaining the down-vote.)  do down-votes enter into the calculation?

Comment: @JosephWright Is there a time interval after which the score is reset? In other words, do very old questions matter?

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'd seen that but as it's not mod-only left it to others to look at :-) The rules as far as we know do count downvotes, but I could only find one in total over all seven questions so hope that in itself is not the issue.

Comment: @becko As I've already mentioned, we don't actually know what the rules are! However, I believe that there is no 'reset' on the ban system: if you don't 'improve' the questions it still counts. In particular, it is documented that deleted questions *do* count.

Comment: The warning comes _long time_ before you actually get Q-banned. It is just a friendly reminder to behave well, and it itself doesn't mean you have to change anything that happened in the past.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, I've checked with with other mods on the network. Broadly, the warning comes about here as you've got a relative small number of questions (currently 7). Of those, two are deleted and there is one downvote on one other: that makes three 'negative events' in seven questions so raises a warning. I note that both the deleted questions were about JabRef and were clearly off-topic for us, so there's not really a chance to edit and improve them for re-opening. As such, the best you can do is make sure new questions are carefully written: with a few more with a positive score you will probably be safe from a ban. Upvoted answers may also help (I'm not 100% about this: as I say in comments, we don't actually know how the ban system algorithm in detail.)

Comment: This is good advice. At a quick glance, @becko, I think you'll be okay if you're careful about [on-topic](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) questions going forward. If you do run into more issues, feel free to e-mail `team@stackexchange.com` (and include a link to this meta question, please).

Answer (score 11):

On the question, how 'well-received' might be defined this excerpt on the 'Curious'-Badge will give some clue or information:

[image]

Perhaps there is another definition behind the 'question-rejection' but otherwise, it could be some explanation, especially the fact, that specific deleted/closed/downvoted questions count thrice.

The excerpt can be found in full extent here: [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)